# How to get all checked value as list on click select all checkbox?

Tags: html, jquery

The `selected_users` list is updating when I click on a checkbox other than `selectall`. When changing `selectall` all are checked/unchecked. So far everything is working fine. I want when `selectall` checked `selected_users` list will have all checked values and if unchecked `selected_users` list will be empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="filter1">
    <input class="selectall" type="checkbox" value="all" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="12" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="18" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="20" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="28" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="39" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="40" name="uid" checked="">
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var selected_users = [];
$(document).on("click", '#filter1 input[type="checkbox"]',function() {
    var searchIDs = $('#filter1 input:checked').not('.selectall').map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    });
    check = searchIDs.get();

    $(".selectall").change(function () {
        $("#filter1 input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
    
    if (check.length === 0){
        selected_users=0
    }else{
        selected_users=check
    }
    
    console.log(selected_users);
});
```

**Log output:**

['2', '5', '7', '12', '18', '20', '28', '39', '40']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few simple issues in your code:

1. You build the `check` array at the start of your event handler, but then after that's done, in the case the `selectall` checkbox was ticked, you change what was checked!  So obviously your `check` array is now inaccurate, in that case.
2. Adding an event handler *inside* another event handler is never a good idea.  Every time a checkbox is changed, you add a new handler for the `selectall` checkbox.  Next time any checkbox is changed, you add another, new event handler for the `selectall` checkbox.  When you change the `selectall` checkbox, all of those stacked up event handlers run!  Adding a new one does not replace the old one, they all just pile up, and they will all run.

The simplest fix I can see is to:

- remove the separate handler for `selectall`.  The other handler handles all checkboxes, so just adapt it to toggle checkboxes if it was the `selectall` checkbox that was changed!  You could do that by testing if it has the expeted class:

  ```
  if ($(this).hasClass('selectall')) {
      $("#filter1 input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  }
  ```
- Next, you have to do that change *before* you build your `check` array, so that the changes are done by that time.
  That's it!  Working snippet below.

```js
var selected_users = [];

$(document).on("click", '#filter1 input[type="checkbox"]', function() {

    // First do any required changes to checkbox states
    if ($(this).hasClass('selectall')) {
        $("#filter1 input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    }

    // Now un/ticking is done, build the list
    var searchIDs = $('#filter1 input:checked').not('.selectall').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    });
    var check = searchIDs.get();

    if (check.length === 0) {
        selected_users=0
    } else {
        selected_users=check
    }

    console.log(selected_users);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter1">
    <input class="selectall" type="checkbox" value="all" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="12" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="18" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="20" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="28" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="39" name="uid" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="40" name="uid" checked="">
</div>
```

Comment: Great, easy fix. Thank you very much To explain very nicely where I went wrong.